# Python subprocess on a different container's shell

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, subprocess, postgis

I have a docker-compose architecture with an API (python) and other containers for specific services. One of these containers is a PostGIS image that I want to call from my API container: One of the endpoints should trigger a `raster2pgsql` command in the postgis container in order to upload a raster to my database. I have been using python subprocess to leverage this inside the API container, but I don't know how to use it to execute the command in the postgis container. Ideas?

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  postgis:
    image: geographica/postgis:dev_diplodocus_raster
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data
      - ./data:/data/mydata
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    links:
      - api
    depends_on:
      - api
    command: tail -F /dev/null
  
  api:
    build: 
      context: ./app
    env_file: &envfile
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: api
 

volumes:
  db-data:
```

I'd normally do

```sh
docker exec postgis bash
>>> raster2pgsql [...]
```

How to call it from the `api` container using python subprocess?

```py
import os
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def upload_raster():
    subprocess.run(
        ['raster2pgsql', ...],
        shell=True,
        timeout=10000,
        check=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
    print('Data has been uploaded')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raster()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put some sort of proper network API (for example, a Flask server) around this process?  Or, can you run the subprocess in the same container as the network service instead of in the database container?  Debugging commands like `docker exec` are difficult to run from inside containers, and there are real security concerns as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze That would be my preferred option indeed.
As I see it that would imply installing postgres + postgis in the API container itself, and getting rid of the `postgis` container?
The only issue wit htat one is getting the installation right in the Dockerfile I guess

Comment: It [looks like](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) `raster2pgsql` just writes out an SQL query as its output.  There's no reason it needs to run in the database container.  The documentation even has an example of piping its output into `psql` to talk to a database that could be adapted for running PostGIS in a separate container.

Comment: That's correct, and that is how I have been using it. But I still need to call `raster2pgsql` in order to obtain the SQL statement. And that's why I am guessing I would need to install postgis in the API container in order to obtain the SQL command...

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to create a bridge network between the containers and use `ssh` to run the command in the other container.

So your docker compose becomes

```
postgis:
    ...
    networks:
        dockernet

api:
    ... 
    networks:
        dockernet

...
volumes:
   db-data:

networks:
    dockernet:
       driver: bridge
```

Make sure you setup an ssh server on the postgis container as well for this to work properly